# I am getting the error in SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')
imputer = imputer.fit(cat_vars[:,2:4])
cat_vars[:,2:4] = imputer.transform(cat_vars[:,2:4])
```

The above is my code for replacing the missing values with the most frequent value in the column index starting from 2 to 3.I am getting the below error. Please suggest why this error is coming. Thanks in advance.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-48eaa0ca1d43> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
      3 imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')
----> 4 imputer = imputer.fit(cat_vars[:,2:4])
      5 cat_vars[:,2:4] = imputer.transform(cat_vars[:,2:4])

TypeError: 'SimpleImputer' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What is `cat_vars`?

Comment: ''cat_vars'' is the name of the data set

Comment: I mean what is the data type? What are the dimensions? If you don't show its assignment, how could anyone know for sure? We are left to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')
imputer = imputer.fit(cat_vars.iloc[:,2:4])
cat_vars.iloc[:,2:4] = imputer.transform(cat_vars.iloc[:,2:4])
```

Comment: Thank you so much..It worked..